# onunload does in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

I am opening a new window as below to

```
var nResult = window.showModalDialog("getSelection.asp?Type=" + inputType, "", "dialogHeight:220px; dialogWidth:400px; resizable=no; help:no; status:no");
```

Now on getSelection.asp I have following syntax for body

```
<BODY onload="RetrieveDialogArguments();document.thisForm.ok.focus();" onunload="ReturnDialogArguments()" >
```

when I put alert then found that `onload` event works and call to `RetrieveDialogArguments()` but `onunload` event does not work and function `ReturnDialogArguments()` does not call. That's why in `nResult` I did not get any value. This call works fine Internet Explorer but not in Google Chrome. Please tell me what is the issue with Google Chrome for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>`onunload` is simply not supported in Chrome or Opera. There's nothing you can do about that.</strike>

Use `onbeforeunload` instead, as in:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () { // stuff here }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `window.onbeforeunload` for Chrome.

Or use [jQuery bind function](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) with `onbeforeunload` event.